# MYSQL Statement with Array Variable

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

So I have the following mysql statement saving to an array:

```
$sql = "SELECT did FROM did WHERE id = '$did_id'";  
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
    while($row = $result->fetch_row()){
       $did[] = $row;
       }
```

That part works great. But now I need to take the values in the $did array and perform another lookup using the values in it. The way it works is we have users assigned to certain did's. So I find the did's that the user is assigned to (the $did array) and only show them results from another table based on those did values. I have no idea how this part works, but this is what my next statement needs to do:

```
   SELECT * FROM log WHERE did_id = "the values in $did array"
```

Hope someone can help. I really appreciate it. I haven't really been able to find anything on it.

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: mysql has no idea what php's array is since it only operates with strings. So try to google about mysql (ansi sql actually) `IN` operator

Comment: @Daniel A. White: **warning** your phrase is nothing more but just a **GUESS**

Answer (score 0):

You can use php's `join` with mysql's `IN` to make comma separated strings you can also use `implode` , [join()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php) is an alias of [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php);

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE did_id IN( ".join(',',$did).")
```

One thing to mention here that your `$did` should contains ids in manner like

```
array("1","2","3"....)
```

So in your loop fetch first index that holds `did` column value

```
$did[] = $row[0];
```

Note: *i assume `did` , `did_id`  type is `int` or `bigint`*

Comment: If `$did` is not of a numeric type - you need to add quotes around, and sanitize the data some way (using something like `mysqli::real_escape_string`) if it's of a character class. Otherwise it will be either syntactically incorrect or a security breach.

Comment: i assume `did` type is int or bigint

Comment: you need to clarify that anyway. If your assumption is wrong - you're doing a bad job for the OP

Comment: I see that. What would OP do if your assumption is wrong? What would further reader do if they found this answer in google and have `varchar`?

Comment: `$did` is an array of arrays, since each `$did` is a `$row` so you need to tweak it further

Comment: @zerkms Developers first learns the types i guess before they start  learn programming this is a basic knowledge for developer that no.s should be declared as numeric or integer ,its no. not character to define the type as char or varchar or text i guess this should comes in the general knowledge part

Comment: $did type is int guys lol. I'll give this a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @dianuj: "that no.s should be declared as numeric or integer" --- you just assume that every column that contains `id` in its name should be numeric. And I don't see what you base your assumption for a general case on.